# Retrieve name value from button in javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown" data-offers-filter-segments="">
  <button class="toggle--dropdown" name="toggle-segment-cagetories-list">
     <span class="dropdown__label" id="dropdown__labelAllCategories">All Categories</span>
  </button>
<div class="dropdown__content" hidden="hidden">
```

Which renders a dropdown, when clicked a new class is appended which is called `is-dropped` so the parent `div` will look like this once its been clicked on `class="dropdown is-dropped"`

Now using Javascript I'm trying to retrieve `name="toggle-segment-cagetories-list"` which we will use within `DTM` (Adobe Tag Manager) as an eVar value but I'm uncertain how I go about retrieving that name value, so far I have the following javascript:

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

if(hasClass(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0], 'is-dropped')){
// Now get the name value ? 
}
else {
  alert("false");
}
```

Now I'm pretty new to `javascript` so if someone can shed some light in how I go about getting the name value and passing it to `DTM` I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you expecting _"toggle-segment-cagetories-list"_ ?

Comment: @Rayon yes, thats correct.

Comment: @Rayon Thanks for the snippet, however I keep getting Invalid or unexpected token when using your code.

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].querySelector('button.toggle--dropdown').getAttribute('name')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
<div class="dropdown is-dropped" data-offers-filter-segments="">
  <button class="toggle--dropdown" name="toggle-segment-cagetories-list">
     <span class="dropdown__label" id="dropdown__labelAllCategories">All Categories</span>
  </button>
<div class="dropdown__content" hidden="hidden">

<script>
var button=document.querySelector('div.is-dropped button.toggle--dropdown');
var name=button&&button.name||'';
alert(name);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your own data-attributes, you need start your attribute name with 'data':

```
   <button class="toggle--dropdown" data-name="toggle-segment-cagetories-list">
```

In order to retrieve the value of the attribute, you can do as shown in the example below:

```
   var article = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle--dropdown');
   article[0].dataset.name // article[0] because getting elements by className returns an array
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to the HTML, so we need to work with the HTML specified above.

Comment: I'm afraid this might be the only way to pass a custom attribute in HTML. Please refer to the following docs: